# Sharing a scanner using SANE on newer Fedora Core versions

Tags: linux, linux-networking, fedora

I'm trying to set up network scanning on a newer Fedora Core 24 machine and all the guides I've been able to find seem to be a bit outdated (Fedora Core 10/14). They talk about setting up a xinetd socket file, and while the folders still present in /etc there are no other signs that xinetd still runs.

So far, I'm not seeing any indications that the server is listening on the correct port for sane (checked using netstat) with the xinet config file setup and I'm strongly suspecting I need to set up the listening socket differently to get a result.

How should I configure sane to listen on the network for requests under Fedora Core 24?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it turns out what I needed to do was define the same socket / daemon information for systemd using a .socket and a .service unit file. The files I've created contain the following contents:

**sane.socket**

```
[Unit]
Description=saned incoming socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=6566
Accept=yes
MaxConnections=1

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

**saned@.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Scanner Service
Requires=saned.socket

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/saned
User=saned
Group=saned
StandardInput=null
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
```

After creating these definition files in /usr/lib/systemd/system all that was needed was:

```
systemctl enable saned.socket
systemctl start saned.socket
```

And now I can access the scanner via the network.

Comment: Where did you create those files?

Comment: In the SystemD unit files folder ( /lib/systemd/system ) on most distributions. See here for more info re SystemD unit files: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-systemd-units-and-unit-files